# struts getting a particular message from request

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts

I have couple of warning messages in the request scope and it is saved like this,

```
     if ((warningMessages != null) && !warningMessages.isEmpty()){
                    // saves message in request scope
                    saveMessages(request, warningMessages);


}
```

and I want to retrive a particular warning message. I did like this,

```
ActionMessages warningMessages = getMessages(request);
```

But nothing is set. Am i missing something or is there any other method to retrive?
Pls advice.

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing is set". Where do you save the messages, and when do you get them? Are both calls done in the same request?